# Tablesorter pager issue with child row

Tags: jquery, tablesorter

I have one child row under Coke in the table. I am wondering why is it being counted as `filteredRows`? How do I make `filteredRows` not including the child rows in the table? And for some reason, if I pick "Uncategorized", it'll say "1 - 1/ 1 (14)" where it should be "- / (14)"

Also, when I search for "coke" and try to expand the child row by clicking on it (after it's being filtered), it won't show the child row.

`Here is the demo`

http://jsfiddle.net/CVVV2/

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

**UPDATE**

Here is the updated demo with the modify code showing `filteredRows` not working properly under "All Items" and "Drinks". Also, I can't expand the child row after searching for "coke" in the search box.

http://jsfiddle.net/CVVV2/9/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out that you'll need to modify [this line](https://github.com/Mottie/tablesorter/blob/master/js/jquery.tablesorter.widgets.js#L926) in the `jquery.tablesorter.widgets.js` file:

```
if (c.pager && c.pager.countChildRows || wo.pager_countChildRows) {
```

to this:

```
if (c.pager && c.pager.countChildRows || wo.pager_countChildRows || wo.filter_childRows) {
```

I'll include this modification in the next update.

Comment: It fixed the issue where there is no entry in the categories, but it's still showing the wrong number of `filteredRows` in the categories that contain "Coke" in this case. And I still can't expand the child rows when searching for "Coke" using that quicksearch plugin. I have the updated jsfiddle with the updated code you provided. Any idea?

Comment: Hmm, I can fix the numbering being off, but I don't know if I can fix the quicksearch issue without modifying it...

Comment: Ok, try version 2.14.4... I still need to work on modifying quicksearch to work with child rows, but I've been sick and sleeping a lot.

Comment: Thank you for the help. I look forward to see the quicksearch code. And hope you'll get better soon!

Comment: Hey @Lancelot... Sorry for the delay. Try this quicksearch mod: https://gist.github.com/Mottie/8078281 (make sure to define the new quicksearch `childRow` option to match the tablesorter `cssChildRow` option). And Merry Christmas!